# Which ports does the Messages app for OS X use?

Tags: network, proxy, messages

If someone has a list of the ports that [Messages](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/messages-beta/) uses I would appreciate that answer here. Extra votes and thanks for providing a reference.

I have searched the knowledgebase and found [this](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS1629), but it only lists iChat ports. I'm assuming Messages replaces iChat, but do they use the same ports? Barring a direct answer, is there an easy way to figure this out with Netstat or some other utility?

Comment: I am going to allow this provisionally - we are discussing the merits of allowing Siri and Messages beta on the meta - please join us and let us know how you feel about this. http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/despite-the-general-rule-to-not-answer-questions-about-beta-products-should-we

Comment: Netstat is deprecated. Try ss: http://linux.die.net/man/8/ss

Comment: Try using Wireshark to scan your outgoing traffic.

Comment: @Moshe Thanks. That was an interesting exercise. So many packets! I think Little Snitch was more clear for me. (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 3):

Using [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html), it reported when Messages is fired up, the following:

[image: Little Snitch's report for Messages application]

And for posterity, here is what the 'FaceTime' application reports as connections, since you can call it up from Messsages (camera icon next to user you're messaging's name):

[image: Little Snitch's report for FaceTime application]

If anyone finds anything different, please add to this answer. (Making it community wiki).

Answer (score 2):

Apple's support FAQ states that TCP ports 80, 443, and 5223 are required for iMessage.

Comment: Haven't heard of Firebind, and that's an excellent tip in of itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it uses the ones for imagent (iChat) tcp  443 and 80

If I remove access to the imagent ports 443 and 80. And try to send a iMessage on my Mac via Little Snitch. These are what Little Snitch will ask for.

You can also use Little Snitch to check what FaceTime ports it is using.

Just remember these are for out going.